# How to change the logo in Stencil.js?

Tags: reactjs, svg, favicon, stenciljs

I want to change the "favicon.ico" default for another logo in Stencil.js

[favicon.ico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvFMz.png)

That is the unique logo that I was found in the project, specifically in "\node_modules@stencil\core\dev-server\static. I tried to overwrited, but I didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the favicon through the page's HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="/path/to/my/favicon.ico">
</head>
```